# simple bit operation for int to short

Tags: java

Having trouble writing the bit operations to convert an int to a short depending on which 16 bits wanted, ex: 1 will be the left most 16 bits and 0 will be the right most 16. All help is appreciated!

```
    /**
 * Get a short from an int.
 * 
 * Examples: 
 *     getShort(0x56781234, 0); // => 0x1234
 *     getShort(0xFF254545, 1); // => 0xFF25
 * 
 * @param num The int to get a short from.
 * @param which Determines which short gets returned - 0 for least-significant short.
 *            
 * @return A short corresponding to the "which" parameter from num.
 */
public static int getShort(int num, int which)
{

    if(which == 1){
        return num>>16;
    }
    else{
        return num << 16;
    }
    }
```

I do not want to use >>> or <<<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will work correctly with both positive and negative numbers:

```
public static int getShort(int num, int which) {
    if(which == 1){
        return num >>> 16; // Use >>> to avoid sign-extending the result
    } else{
        return num & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does >>> mean? is there a way to present it in just >>?

Comment: @JamesCarter Yes, you can use `(num >> 16) & 0xFFFF`, but `>>>` is shorter, and it is designed to deal with the situation that you have. The regular `>>` sign-extends negative numbers, meaning that when you right-shift a negative, its most significant bit gets copied in the upper 16 bits; the resultant `int` will be negative. When you use `>>>`, zeros are shifted from the left.

Comment: Great, makes sense! working on a different one where I deal with the abs of a value. Probably will use the same situation

Answer (score 1):

The

```
    return num << 16;
```

should read

```
    return num & 0xFFFF;
```

Also,

```
    return num >> 16;
```

should read

```
    return num >>> 16;
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, mind elaborating what you were trying to do?

Comment: Also probably you want `public static short int`